# Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning in Repository class

Tags: node.js

**CreateMemberController**

```
    export class CreateMemberController extends BaseController {
              private memberrRepo: IMemberRepository;
            
              constructor(memberRepo: IMemberRepository) {
                super();
                this.memberrRepo = memberRepo;
              }
            
              protected async executeImpl(
                request: express.Request,
                response: express.Response
              ): Promise<void | any> {
                
                  
                  try {
                     const member = new Member();
                     member.firstName = firstName;
                    let user = this.memberrRepo.add(member); 
                  } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                  }
                }  
               
            }
```

**MemberRepository**

```
export class MemberRepository implements IMemberRepository {
           
          async add(model: Member): Promise<Member | null> {
            try {
              const userRepository = getRepository(Member);
              const savedUser = userRepository.save(model);
              return savedUser;
            } catch (e) {
               
              return Promise.reject(new Error()); < === where exception occurs
            }
          }
          
        }
```

Above class 1 CreateMemberController calls the method called add to save data into the database.But following error occurs
**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error**
It comes from MemberRepository class.I put a mark on the code

Comment: Your `add` method is async. But when you call it in `executeImpl` you are not `await`ing it. Thus `let user = this.memberrRepo.add(member);` is just assigning `user` to be a Promise, which rejection you don't catch (No, the `catch` in `executeImpl` doesn't catch rejections from promises that are not awaited ...)

Comment: @derpirscher Can you elaborate the answer.I m very new to the NODE.js

Comment: use `let user = await this.memberRepo.add(member);`

Comment: @derpirscher thank you  for answer  is it possible to explain this little bit more //No, the catch in executeImpl doesn't catch rejections from promises that are not awaited .//

Comment: as an unawaited promise is executed asynchronously, it's not finished yet, when the codeblock encapsulated by `try` ends. And the `catch` can only catch exceptions which happen during the execution of that codeblock.  You should probably read one or two of the plenty of tutorials on async programming, execution stack ... in javascript to gain a deeper understanding on how this works.